# Фича C++ или компилятора VS?

Tags: c++, преобразование

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int result = 0;
    int a = 1;
    float b = 0.016;
    result = a - b;
    cout << result;  // = 0.
    cout << '\n';
    result = a + b;
    cout << result;  // = 1.
    cin.get();
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Собственно вопрос: Почему во втором случаи не получается 2? Или в первом не вышло 1?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В ваших примерах результаты выражений, которые имеют тип `float` присваиваются переменной `result`, которая имеет тип `int`

```
int result = 0;
^^^
```

В этом случае дробная часть отбрасывается.

Поэтому вы имеете:

1. Резальтат выражения

   a - b

равен

```
`0.984`
```

При присваивании его целочисленной переменной получается `0`. То есть дробная часть была отброшена.

2. Результат выражения

   a + b

равен

```
1.016
```

При присваивании его целочисленной переменной получается `1`. То есть опять-таки дробная часть была отброшена.

Обратите внимание на преобразования к целому типу, когда результат выражения - отрицательное число.

Допустим, что имеются следующие объявления

```
int a = -1;
float b = 0.016;
```

где переменная `a` имеет значение `-1`.

Тогда выражение

```
a + b
```

будет равно

```
-0.984
```

Однако при присвоение результата целочисленной переменной получится значение `0`.

Для выражения

```
a - b
```

результатом будет

```
-1.016
```

Однако при присвоении его целочисленной переменной получится -1.

Дело в том, что в C++ и в C отбрасывание дробной части происходит по направлению к 0.

Answer (score 4):

При приведении типа `float` к `int` дробная часть отбрасывается.

```
1 - 0.016 = 0.984 -> 0
1 + 0.016 = 1.016 -> 1
```

Это - фича языка, не компилятора

Answer (score 0):

Несоответствие типов данных, `int` - целочисленный тип, который округляет значение, но не по правилам математики, а в сторону меньшего значения.